# How can I stop a bluetooth keyboard from waking my Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake, monterey

I use my 2019 MacBook Pro with a Magic Keyboard via Bluetooth. When the MBP is in sleep mode, I can wake it up by pressing a key on the keyboard.

I would like to change it so key presses on the Magic Keyboard are ignored. I still want it to wake up easily otherwise - if possible by pressing any key on the integrated MBP keyboard, or by some other simple means (i.e. by a quick press on the on/off button).

I do not wish to turn off the Magic Keyboard, to disable Bluetooth or to disconnect the device in the Bluetooth settings.

Is there a way to achieve this? I checked the settings, and found no option to disallow a specific device to influence sleep mode...

Comment: Perhaps this [person can share their setup or swap hardware](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/437367/5472)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like Apple have removed the `Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer` option in MacOS Monterey (12.2.1) for some reason.

The solution from [this post on MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/monterey-bluetooth-wake-issue.2319613/post-30819437) solved the issue for me on my M1 MacBook:

```
brew install sleepwatcher blueutil
echo "$(which blueutil) -p 0" > ~/.sleep
echo "$(which blueutil) -p 1" > ~/.wakeup
chmod 755 ~/.sleep ~/.wakeup
brew services restart sleepwatcher
```

If you don't have `brew`, the installation instructions can be found at https://brew.sh

Comment: This did not work for me on my 2018 Macbook pro running Monterey 12.2.1

Comment: The code given is different from the source. Line 2 and 3 suppose to be: echo "/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p 0" > ~/.sleep && echo "/usr/local/bin/blueutil -p 1" > ~/.wakeup

Comment: As that MacRumors forum post says, the location that brew installs to is different on M1/ARM Macs. My solution uses the new install location.
The best thing to do is run `which blueutil` and find out where it has been installed on your system.

Comment: I've updated my answer to just use the `which` command inline to make this answer more universal

Comment: The previously accepted answer from @pmagwood does not seem to work in Monterey anymore - this one does now.

Comment: This works well! Apparently, it's not necessary to grant `sleepwatch` access to the keystrokes to support these sleep- and wake-scripts. (That's probably only needed for idle detection.)
The activation of bluetooth on wake seems to take quite long, though, about 10-15 seconds.

Comment: For me, blueutil is now at `/opt/homebrew/bin/blueutil` - best to use `$(which blueutil)` to ensure you get the correct path.

Comment: This worked for me on a MBP M1 running Ventura. I didn't give it keystroke permissions as they are not needed (at least for my use case)

Comment: This works on my MacBook Pro M2 running Ventura, but it takes about 20 seconds for bluetooth to be reactivated which is not great. Any idea how to make it quicker?

Comment: Why... would I have to write a shell script for such a feature?! I constantly hear that that Macs have great UX, yet I often stumble upon various issues that can only be solved via CLI. Even something as simple as Cut/Paste seems impossible on Mac without either aligning two windows on top of each other so that you can do a drag and drop, or running a CLI command.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can achieve this through the Bluetooth settings.  See this article for guidance:  [OSXDaily - Try Preventing the Bluetooth Wake Ability if Your Mac is Randomly Waking from Sleep](https://osxdaily.com/2014/05/30/prevent-bluetooth-waking-mac-from-sleep/)

In summary:

1. ** Menu --> System Preferences --> Bluetooth**
2. Click the *Advanced* button (lower right corner)
3. Uncheck the "Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer" option

If the option is not there, it may be related to a bug (feature?) with Monterey.
Try setting the preference using terminal:

`defaults -currentHost write com.apple.Bluetooth RemoteWakeEnabled 0`

Comment: I do not have this option. If I click "Advanced" (in my German version: "Weitere Optionen..."), I only get to choose whether I want to start the Bluetooth Assistant if no device is available during startup (exactly the two options in the screenshot in that article), and the third option does not show at all for me...

Comment: I think you are encountering a bug in the macos.  I don't see it explicitly in your question but your tag makes me assume you are running Monterey.
Can you confirm?

As far as apple is concerned in their documentation, the option should be there:
[link](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/wake-mac-a-wireless-keyboard-mouse-trackpad-mchlp2664/mac)

Others have the same issue after upgrading
[link](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/monterey-bluetooth-wake-issue.2319613/)
[link](https://www.reddit.com/r/macbookair/comments/qg2xsk/after_monterey_update_keyboard_and_mouse_wake_up/)

Comment: On a macos 10.13.6 system I was successfully able to edit this checkbox using the terminal.  Please try the following to see if it affects the remote wake preference on your system:

`defaults -currentHost write com.apple.Bluetooth RemoteWakeEnabled 0` . 

(You can verify the setting was written by executing `defaults -currentHost read com.apple.Bluetooth`).
You can always re-enable the preference by changing the 0 to a 1 in the above code

Comment: awesome, thanks! And yes, this is indeed on Monterey.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Open my Airpod Pro still wake my Macbook pro all the time.

Comment: The Monterey shit does not have it, the version before (BigSiur) had it. I remember, I bet reptilians removed that to annoy me!

Comment: This did not work for me on my 2018 Macbook pro running Monterey 12.2.1

Comment: This is a very outdated answer, they removed this advanced options a while ago and that's probably the reason why OP asked the question in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I discovered this simple free mac app that turns off bluetooth when the mac goes to sleep (and turns it back on when it wakes)

https://github.com/odlp/bluesnooze/

Works like a charm!

Comment: In MacOS 12.5.1, this does not work. The application *does* successfully disable Bluetooth, but the Mac wakes back up anyway and the application does not re-enable Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2):

For Logitech-Options users:

Try either removing the permissions in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Input Monitoring** > **Logitech Options Daemons**

or

Try installing "Logi Options+" instead of "Logitech-Options".

Comment: _Try installing "Logi Options+" instead of "Logitech-Options"._ Not quite ! "Logi Options+" barely supports older model. This requiring both if you switch between different places with different peripherals.