# macOs don't wake up on bluetooth, build in keyboard

Tags: sleep-wake

I have a really annoying problem with macOs Monterey and my MacBook Pro. It's mostly connected to an external monitor and wireless keyboard and mouse from Logitech.

Lately it won't wake up from sleep when pressing the keyboard. And even if I open the lid and press a key on the built in keyboard it doesn't wakes up. I need to press the power button for it to wake up.

Any ideas how to solve this?

UPDATE: Seems like this actually is caused by Parallells Desktop. Seems to work a lot better when I'm not running a VM and wake up the computer.

Comment: I wonder if the machine is really asleep if the built in keyboard isn’t responsive. Does this recur if you disconnect everything from the Mac and [turn off Bluetooth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/431815/5472)?