# How can I stop a particular BT device from waking my computer in Monterey?

Tags: bluetooth, sleep-wake, monterey

https://superuser.com/questions/1411369/prevent-headphones-from-waking-up-my-macbook -- doesn't answer the question as the Advanced button is gone:

[image: BT prefs]

Holding down option doesn't do anything either.

[How can I stop a bluetooth keyboard from waking my Macbook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431812/how-can-i-stop-a-bluetooth-keyboard-from-waking-my-macbook-pro) doesn't answer how to disable a specific device.

Is there a way to turn off "wake with bluetooth" for a specific device via the Terminal? My BT headphones and my Trackpad seem to trigger a wake from sleep and it's irritating me.