# "Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer" not in Monterey, is there a command to change this setting?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth

Since Apple removed the option, is there a way to get it back with the command line? I'd like my headphones not to wake the Mac up every time I put these on my head

I've searched everywhere and could not find any command, so I don't have high hopes. lol

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/437396/202515 does this solution work for you?

Comment: i shall check this out,thanks .it basically turns bt off and on depending on sleep state correct ? won't it drain battery a lot by enabling/disabling bluetooth ?