# How to prevent my Airpods Pro Gen 2 from waking my sleeping MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, sleep-wake, airpods

I use my AirPods Pro 2 for both my MacBook but also on another device. What I notice is that when my MacBook is asleep, but I take out my AirPods, it will cause my MacBook to wake up.

I looked through the settings in my MacBook but I only see the basic bluetooth options for the AirPods. I can't seem to find a setting to ensure my MacBook doesn't auto-wake up from AirPods or any Bluetooth item.

Answer (score 1):

Good guess! There is indeed a way to overcome this issue by using command line: [How can I stop a bluetooth keyboard from waking my Macbook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431812/how-can-i-stop-a-bluetooth-keyboard-from-waking-my-macbook-pro#answer-437396)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, wouldn't it be easier just to disable bluetooth and only use while needed?

Comment: You lose the "Find My" feature AND it's really boring and difficult to remember to always turn off bluetooth at the end of the working day. I'm in the same situation as the OP and I did try your idea, but it's not a real solution.